# List unique and count the first numberic match after a string

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I would like to list each unique number after a specific string and a count of how many times this number occurs in a file. The specific string would be 'length' and the first number after it.

**Current data for example:**

```
*random string* length: 40
*random string* length: 54
*random string* length: 40
*random string* length: 60
*random string* length: 60
*random string* length: 60
```

**Ideal result would be:**

```
length 40: 2
length 54: 1
length 60: 3
```

At the moment I am scripting a count of each number I manually see in a 24,111 line file which isn't practical.

`cat file.txt | awk '/length: 60/ {total++} END {print total}'`

Comment: let me know if you want an answer in python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
match($0,/length: [0-9]+/){
  cnts[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++
}
END{
  for(key in cnts){
    print key": "cnts[key]
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `match` function to match string `length: digits` in all lines then creating array with 2nd field and keep adding its value to same index. In `END` block of code printing index and value of array as per shown required output.

Comment: I have tried this, and the result gave me the total amount of lines in the file. Same as you would do:
wc -l Input_file

Which isn't right as I know there are at least 3 or 4 different unique numbers occuring multiple times in the one file. I was hoping to count each unique number to see how many times it occurs in the file

Comment: @nobody-at-all, When I run my code it works fine for me with your shown samples. Does your actual file has `Some random length: 40` kind of lines only?

Comment: No it doesn't. My actual code looks like this:
protocol 6 offset (bytes) 0 flags [none] length: 588 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.3.2) 
protocol 4 offset (bytes) 3 flags [none] length: 58 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.3.2) 
protocol 5 offset (bytes) 2 flags [none] length: 78 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.3.2) 

where the length before the specific string is a random length

Comment: @nobody-at-all, Then please do update your question with correct samples, else its hard to help with code if samples shown are different from your actual input.

Comment: I have updated. Please see *random string* where this length is random and needs to be ignored and only counting the first match of length: and number after

Comment: @nobody-at-all, please check my edited code and let me know then?

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much! I very much appreciate your time

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care where the count appears in the output:

```
$ sed 's/.*\(length\):/\1/' file | sort | uniq -c
      2 length 40
      1 length 54
      3 length 60
```

or if you need exactly the output format in your question:

```
$ sed 's/.*\(length\):/\1/' file | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2, $3":", $1}'
length 40: 2
length 54: 1
length 60: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/.* (\S+:.*)/\1 1/;H;x;s/(\n[^:]*: \S+ )(\S+)(.*)\1.*$/\1$((\2+1))\3/
        x;$!d;x;s/.(.*)/echo "\1"/e' file
```

Remove junk from the start of each line and add a counter.

Append the amended line to the hold space and increment the counter if the line already exists (removing the duplicate) and then delete the current line.

At the end of file, swap to the hold space, remove the introduced newline at the start of the hold space, create an echo command and evaluate it.